# Group by : To get the column value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table with two column [item,booking] .
the values are

```
item      booking
Cont1     bkg1
cont2     bkg1
cont3     bkg1
cont4     bkg2
cont5     bkg3
```

i need a result should be like below :

```
   item     booking
    cont1    bkg1
```

I have a condition like if the 'one valid booking with multiple item' means display the result.
Thanks for your valuable results.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why you get `Cont1     bkg1` and not `Cont2     bkg1`?

Comment: because  'bkg1' used with multiple item [Cont1,cont2,cont3] but other's are used only one time with item.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Look closer and answer again.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, Sorry for the misunderstanding, i need to return only the row which is the minimum of the item 'Cont1 bkg1' not to return with multiple rows.

Comment: thanks @HamletHakobyan, i got it.
SELECT min(item),booking from booking_tb
group by booking
having count(distinct item) > 1 ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select min(item), booking
from your table
group by booking
having count(distinct item) > 1;
```